# Matching values in hash tables while ignoring case sensitivity betwen two CSV files

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to append a column by seeing if the value of the column from CSV file2 is contained in CSV file1.

I have a CSV file1 (`test1.csv`):

```
csv1ColumnOne,csv1ColumnTwo
1,dF3aWv
2,
3,ka21p
4,NAE31
5,dsafl
6,nv02k
7,qng02
8,xcw3r
9,dF3aW
```

I have a CSV file2 (`test2.csv`):

```
csv2ColumnOne,csv2ColumnTwo
bbetfe,DF3AW
asdf,dsafl
qwer,
zxcv,NAE31
poiu,nbrwp1
```

Given the following code...

```
$hashTable = @()
Import-Csv C:\path\test1.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $hashTable[$_.csv1ColumnOne] = $_.csv1ColumnTwo
}

(Import-Csv C:\path\test2.csv) |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='csv1ColumnThree';e={
    if ($hashTable.ContainsKey($_.csv2ColumnTwo)) {
      $_.csv2ColumnTwo
    } elseif (-not ($_.csv2ColumnTwo)) {
      'No value found from csv file2'
    } else {
      'No value found from csv file1'
    }
  }} | Export-Csv "C:\path\testresults.csv" -NoType
```

The results look like this:

```
csv2ColumnOne,csv2ColumnTwo,csv1ColumnThree
bbetfe,DF3AW,"No value found from csv file1"
asdf,dsafl,dsafl
qwer,,No value found from csv file2
zxcv,NAE31,NAE31
poiu,nbrwp1,"No value found from csv file1"
```

When instead it should look like this:

```
csv2ColumnOne,csv2ColumnTwo,csv1ColumnThree
bbetfe,DF3AW,dF3aW
asdf,dsafl,dsafl
qwer,,"No value found from csv file2"
zxcv,NAE31,NAE31
poiu,nbrwp1,"No value found from csv file1"
```

The reason I see `bbetfe,DF3AW,"No value found from csv file1"` ins't `bbetfe,DF3AW,dF3aW` is because of the case sensitivity of the value. Anyway to ignore the case sensitivity with alpha-numeric values?

Comment: Note, I cannot use the `-like` because it will fill in the value `dF3aWv` instead of `dF3aW` for column `csv1ColumnThree`... Python has something like if (string.upper()). It would be great if powershell had something like this...

Answer (score 4):

Lookups with `ContainsKey()` already are case-insensitive. You're just using the wrong data structure, and using it in the wrong way, too.

If you want to look up a *key* in a hashtable you need to actually use the data you want to look up as the *key* of the hashtable:

```
$hashTable[$_.csv1ColumnTwo] = $_.csv1ColumnOne
```

For looking up something in the *values* of a hashtable use `ContainsValue()`.

However, since you just want to check if the second column of the first CSV contains a the value from the second column of the second CSV you don't need a hashtable in the first place. A simple array will suffice.

```
$list = Import-Csv 'C:\path\test1.csv' | Select-Object -Expand csv1ColumnTwo

Import-Csv 'C:\path\test2.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='csv1ColumnThree';e={
    if ($list -contains $_.csv2ColumnTwo) {
      $_.csv2ColumnTwo
    } elseif (-not ($_.csv2ColumnTwo)) {
      'No value found from csv file2'
    } else {
      'No value found from csv file1'
    }
  }} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\testresults.csv' -NoType
```

If you don't want empty strings "found" in the second CSV simply exclude the element from `$list`:

```
$list = Import-Csv 'C:\path\test1.csv' |
        Select-Object -Expand csv1ColumnTwo |
        Where-Object { $_ }  # allow only non-empty values
```

Not every problem is a nail, so don't try to fix everything with a hammer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the correction on my part. The hammer theory I agree with, but when you have no lead dev or agile environment, and the manager is expecting you to make changes and push things out within 10 minutes, i have little time for re-factoring/redesign :(

Comment: Seems to work, What if I want to use the value from the first file instead of copying the value from the second value to column `csv1ColumnThree`?

Comment: You could use a hashtable mapping the value from the first CSV to itself (`$hashTable[$_.csv1ColumnTwo] = $_.csv1ColumnTwo`), so you can use a lookup `$hashTable[$_.csv2ColumnTwo]`, or you can get it from the array like this: `$v = $_.csv2ColumnTwo; $list | ? {$_ -eq $v}`.

Comment: So for example, value1 (with uppercase and lowercase) is from file1 and value2 (uppercase only) is from file2. In the code, I am temporarily assigning the value1 to uppercase only so the match will be found. However when plugging in value1, I want it to be the original upper/lower case chars. in short I want `dF3aW` and not `DF3AW` in the column3. Is there an easy way to do this? Does powershell support a pass-by-assignment like python does?

Comment: Please re-read my answer. The lookups already are case-insensitive. You don't need to upper- or lowercase anything for that. Your problem wasn't due to case-sensitive lookups, but because you used the wrong CSV column as the key in the hashtable.

Comment: in your answer you have it output `$_.csv2ColumnTwo`, what I need is to have it output `$_.csv1ColumnTwo` | where `$_.csv1ColumnTwo` and `$_.csv2ColumnTwo` match (non-case sensitive).

Comment: My answer has `$_.csv2ColumnTwo` because that's what you output in your question. Ways to get the corresponding value from the first CSV are outlined in my first comment above. The lookups are still case-insensitive and don't need upper- or lowercasing.

Comment: ah for some reason the first comment wasn't showing yet. Okay I will try that (The method with the array). Thanks again.

Comment: I'm getting nothing but blank values now. Maybe i'm putting out the wrong syntax? `Select-Object -Property *, @{n='csv1ColumnThree';e={$v = $_.csv2ColumnTwo;$list | ? {$_ -eq $v} ElseIf (-not($_.csv2ColumnTwo)){'No value found from csv file2'}Else {'No value found from csv file1'}}} | Export-Csv`. please forgive me as I have never delt with a ternary operator with powershell (assuming that is what the ? means...).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98179/discussion-between-fiddle-freak-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Comment: Ah okay I found it... the lookup needs to be in the if statement - `Select-Object -Property *, @{n='csv1ColumnThree';e={if($list -contains $_.csv2ColumnTwo){$v = $_.csv2ColumnTwo;$list | ? {$_ -eq $v}} ElseIf (-not($_.csv2ColumnTwo)){'No value found from csv file2'}Else {'No value found from csv file1'}}} | Export-Csv`. My issue now is I am seeing `qwer,,` instead of `qwer,,"No value found from csv file2"`. So the elseif is not being checked...

Comment: yeah, even using your code directly with the files given as is in the question, the elseif statement is not being printed on the 2nd file in row `qwer,,`. It should be printing as `qwer,,"No value found from csv file2"`. Thanks for your patience and please answer this when you get the chance.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to convert the string to lower case, just use the `-icontains` comparison operator (the "i" means case insenstive comparison):

So instead of

```
If ($hashTable.ContainsKey($_.csv2ColumnTwo)){
```

try this:

```
If ($hashTable.keys -icontains $_.csv2ColumnTwo){
```

Comment: For some reason, it's still printing the else statement :(

Answer (score 1):

can you just make them all lowercase?

```
$a = ipcsv 'C:\path\test1.csv'
$a | % {$_.csv1columntwo = $_.csv1columntwo.tolower()}
$a

$b = ipcsv 'C:\path\test2.csv'
$b | % {$_.csv2ColumnOne = $_.csv2ColumnOne.tolower(); $_.csv2ColumnTwo = $_.csv2ColumnTwo.tolower()}
$b
```

Comment: let me give this a shot. Actually i can't write them as lower, they have to be non-tampered with, but if I could read them as lower, that would work...

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me, i'm going to give the answer above a shot, that seems easier and less to change... Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Ansgar basically had the right answer, but with a bug. it was printing the row in the second file as `qwer,,` when instead it should have printed `qwer,,No value found from csv file2`. There is another condition that needed to be added in the first if statement as shown below.

```
$list = Import-Csv 'C:\path\test1.csv' | Select-Object -Expand csv1ColumnTwo

Import-Csv 'C:\path\test2.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='csv1ColumnThree';e={
    if (($list -contains $_.csv2ColumnTwo) -and ($_.csv2ColumnTwo)) {
      $_.csv2ColumnTwo
    } elseif (-not ($_.csv2ColumnTwo)) {
      'No value found from csv file2'
    } else {
      'No value found from csv file1'
    }
}} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\testresults.csv' -NoType
```

The empty values in the 2nd file were being checked as true, so the elseif was never being reached.